# Complex future unwraping

Tags: scala, future

I know I can unwrap

```
Future[Future[Seq]] => Future[Seq]
```

With flatMap function

But how do I get following mapping?

```
Future[Seq[Future[Seq]]] => Future[Seq[Seq]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Future.sequence` will change a `Seq[Future[...]]` to a `Future[Seq[...]]`

So, something like this: `obj.flatMap(x => Future.sequence(x))` perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This worked like magic to me:

```
implicit class RichFutureSeqFutures[A](futureSeqFutures: Future[Seq[Future[A]]]) {
  def flattenInner: Future[Seq[A]] = {
    futureSeqFutures flatMap {Future.collect(_)}
  }
}
```

Source from https://coveralls.io/builds/3016777/source?filename=utils%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fscala%2Fcom%2Ftwitter%2Ffinatra%2Fconversions%2Ffuture.scala "here".

Comment: Error: value `collect` is not a member of object `scala.concurrent.Future`